# Pandas merging dataframes and overwriting the data in the original df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I'm trying to merge two pandas dataframes but I can't figure out how to get the result I need. These are the example versions of dataframes I'm looking at:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([["09/10/2019",None],["10/10/2019",None], ["11/10/2019",6],
                    ["12/10/2019",5], ["13/10/2019",3], ["14/10/2019",3],
                    ["15/10/2019",5],
                    ["16/10/2019",None]], columns = ['Date', 'A'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([["10/10/2019",3], ["11/10/2019",5], ["12/10/2019",6],
                    ["13/10/2019",1], ["14/10/2019",2], ["15/10/2019",4]],
                    columns = ['Date', 'A'])
```

I have checked the [Pandas merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101) but still can't find the way to do it correctly. Essentially what I need using the same graphics as in the guide is this:

[image]

i.e. I want to keep the data from df1 that falls outside the shared keys section, but within shared area I want df2 data from column 'A' to overwrite data from df1. I'm not even sure that `merge` is the right tool to use.

I've tried using `df1 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='right', on='Date')` with different options, but in most cases it creates two separate columns - `A_x` and `A_y` in the output.

This is what I want to get as the end result:

```
         Date    A
0  09/10/2019  NaN
1  10/10/2019  3.0
2  11/10/2019  5.0
3  12/10/2019  6.0
4  13/10/2019  1.0
5  14/10/2019  2.0
6  15/10/2019  4.0
7  16/10/2019  NaN
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a way using [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
df2.set_index('Date').combine_first(df1.set_index('Date')).reset_index()
```

Or [`reindex_like`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_like.html):

```
df2.set_index('Date').reindex_like(df1.set_index('Date')).reset_index()
```

---

```
         Date    A
0  09/10/2019  NaN
1  10/10/2019  3.0
2  11/10/2019  5.0
3  12/10/2019  6.0
4  13/10/2019  1.0
5  14/10/2019  2.0
6  15/10/2019  4.0
7  16/10/2019  NaN
```